Questions in Poisson integral in Rudin RCA 11.17
11.17 Poisson Integrals of Measures
If $\mu$ is a complex measure on $T$, and if we want to replace integrals over $T$ by integrals over intervals of length $2 \pi$ in $R^1$, these intervals have to be taken half open, because of the possible presence of point masses in $\mu$. To avoid this (admittedly very minor) problem, we shall keep integration on the circle in what follows, and will write the Poisson integral $u=P[d \mu]$ of $\mu$ in the form
$$
u(z)=\int_T P\left(z, e^{i t}\right) d \mu\left(e^{i t}\right) \quad(z \in U)
$$
where $P\left(z, e^{i t}\right)=\left(1-|z|^2\right) /\left|e^{i t}-z\right|^2$, as in formula 11.5(6).
The reasoning that led to Theorem 11.7 applies without change to Poisson integrals of measures. Thus $u$, defined by (1), is harmonic in $U$.
My questions:

Why should we fix this "minor problem", i.e. what would happen if I don't deal with it？

I think all the reasoning behind Poisson integral is still true if I don't fix it.

How can I deduce that $u$ is harmonic in $U$ like 11.7?

In 11.7, we first assume that $f$ is real, and change the form into a real part of a holomorphic function. But now the measure is a complex one and can I change the order of integral and the "Re" operation?
11.5 The Poisson Kernel This is the function
$$
P_r(t)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|} e^{i n t} \quad(0 \leq r<1, t \text { real }) .
$$
We may regard $P_r(t)$ as a function of two variables $r$ and $t$ or as a family of functions of $t$, indexed by $r$.
If $z=r e^{i \theta}(0 \leq r<1, \theta$ real $)$, a simple calculation, made in Sec. 5.24 , shows that
$$
P_r(\theta-t)=\operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{e^{i t}+z}{e^{i t}-z}\right]=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2 r \cos (\theta-t)+r^2}
$$
From (1) we see that
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(t) d t=1 \quad(0 \leq r<1) .
$$
From (2) it follows that $P_r(t)>0, P_r(t)=P_r(-t)$, that
$$
P_r(t)<P_r(\delta) \quad(0<\delta<|t| \leq \pi),
$$
and that
$$
\lim _{r \rightarrow 1} P_r(\delta)=0 \quad(0<\delta \leq \pi)
$$
These properties are reminiscent of the trigonometric polynomials $Q_k(t)$ that were discussed in Sec. 4.24.
The open unit disc $D(0 ; 1)$ will from now on be denoted by $U$. The unit circle - the boundary of $U$ in the complex plane - will be denoted by $T$. Whenever it is convenient to do so, we shall identify the spaces $L^p(T)$ and $C(T)$ with the corresponding spaces of $2 \pi$-periodic functions on $R^1$, as in Sec. 4.23.
One can also regard $P_r(\theta-t)$ as a function of $z=r e^{i \theta}$ and $e^{i t}$. Then (2) becomes
$$
P\left(z, e^{i t}\right)=\frac{1-|z|^2}{\left|e^{i t}-z\right|^2}
$$
for $z \in U, e^{i t} \in T$.
11.6 The Poisson Integral
If $f \in L^1(T)$ and
$$
F\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(\theta-t) f(t) d t,
$$
then the function $F$ so defined in $U$ is called the Poisson integral of $f$. We shall sometimes abbreviate the relation (1) to
$$
F=P[f] .
$$
If $f$ is real, formula $11.5(2)$ shows that $P[f]$ is the real part of
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{i t}+z}{e^{i t}-z} f(t) d t
$$
which is a holomorphic function of $z=r e^{i \theta}$ in $U$, by Theorem 10.7. Hence $P[f]$ is harmonic in $U$. Since linear combinations (with constant coefficients) of harmonic functions are harmonic, we see that the following is true:
11.7 Theorem
If $f \in L^1(T)$ then the Poisson integral $P[f]$ is a harmonic function in $U$.
10.7 Theorem
Suppose $\mu$ is a complex (finite) measure on a measurable space $X, \varphi$ is a complex measurable function on $X, \Omega$ is an open set in the plane which does not intersect $\varphi(X)$, and
$$
f(z)=\int_X \frac{d \mu(\zeta)}{\varphi(\zeta)-z} \quad(z \in \Omega)
$$
Then $f$ is representable by power series in $\Omega$.

"minor problem":  Suppose the integrand is zero everywhere except for unit point masses at $2\pi \Bbb{Z}$.  Integrated over $[0,2\pi]$, you get $2$, over $[0,2\pi)$ or $(0,1\pi]$, you get $1$, and over $(0,2\pi)$, you get $0$.  So to not double-count the point masses and not fail to account for the point masses, we only include the one from one end of the interval.  (Equivalently, we want the line to be a covering space for the circle, so when we pull back to the line, we get an interval that is missing one end point.)

The use of a whole circle instead of a half-open interval in integrals, if the measure is known to be non-negative, covers point masses.  A complex measure can have a non-zero amount of probability at just one point. If the concept of integration was used over a half-open interval [a, b), point mass at b would be omitted, whereas point mass at a would be included introducing asymmetry. Integration of the circle clears the doubts since there are no endpoints.
On the other hand, harmonicity of Poisson's integral $u(z) = \int_T P(z, e^{it}) d\mu(e^{it})$ was pointed out through the properties of the Poisson kernel and linearity of integral which were used for this demonstration. Poisson kernel, which $P(z, e^{it})$ is equal to $\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{it}-z|^2},$ is harmonic in $z$ at any given $e^{it}$ and thus can be presented as the real element of a complex function:
$$ P(z, e^{it}) = \operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z}\right) $$
Now, in order to see that $u(z)$ is a harmonic function, we split the complex measure $\mu$ into $\mu = \mu_1 + i\mu_2$, where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the finite signed measures.  Each of the signed measures can be more deeply broken down (due to the Hahn decomposition theorem) into the difference between the two positive measures:  $\mu_1 = \mu_1^+ - \mu_1^-$ and $\mu_2 = \mu_2^+ - \mu_2^-$. Due to the linearity of the integral, we have:
$$ u(z) = \int_T P(z, e^{it}) d\mu = \int_T P(z, e^{it}) d(\mu_1^+ - \mu_1^- + i(\mu_2^+ - \mu_2^-)) = \int_T P(z, e^{it}) d\mu_1^+ - ... + i\int_T P(z, e^{it}) d\mu_2^- $$
Since $P(z, e^{it})$ is constant and its maximum is positive when $z$ is the center of the circle, we can switch Re with the integral for every term with a positive measure (particularly, it is accepted by monotone or dominated convergence theorem).  Then we recombine these terms back and we arrive at
$$ u(z) = \operatorname{Re}\left[\int_T \left(\frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z}\right) d\mu_1^+\right] - ... + i\operatorname{Re}\left[\int_T \left(\frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z}\right) d\mu_2^-\right] = \operatorname{Re}\left[\int_T \left(\frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z}\right) d\mu\right] $$
The function $\frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}$ is analytical in $z$ for $|z| < 1$. Consequently, the integral of it concerning the complex measure $\mu$ is also holomorphic (by the theorem 10.7). Thus, $u(z)$ is the real part of a holomorphic function, which shows that it is harmonic.
